# An error occured while loading data by using dataset and dataloader of torch.utils.data. TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()

Tags: python, pytorch

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()
```

I think the error occured while loading image datasets. What does this error mean?

I have already searched many examples in github or surfing, there aren't any examples what I exactly want.

The code is:

```
class MakeDataSet(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data_path, transform=None):
        self.file_names = glob(data_path)
        self.labels = []
        self.transform = transform
        for LA in self.file_names:
            if 'cat' in LA:
                self.labels.append(0)
            if 'dog' in LA:
                self.labels.append(1)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        img = Image.open(self.file_names[index])
        if self.transform is not None:
            img = self.transform(img)

        label = torch.from_numpy(np.array(self.labels[index]))
        return img, label

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.file_names)


transformation = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()])
DB = MakeDataSet(img_path, transform=transformation)
loader = DataLoader(MakeDataSet, batch_size=5, shuffle=True)
```

The full error message is:

```
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1689, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1683, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1083, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/BJ/PycharmProjects/AlexNet/test.py", line 45, in <module>
    loader = DataLoader(MakeDataSet, batch_size=5, shuffle=True)
  File "C:\Users\BJ\Anaconda3\envs\install_pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 802, in __init__
    sampler = RandomSampler(dataset)
  File "C:\Users\BJ\Anaconda3\envs\install_pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\sampler.py", line 60, in __init__
    self.num_samples = len(self.data_source)
TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `self.file_names`. Once you figure this out, maybe you'll find the source of the error. I am not sure what data you are using, but `self.file_names = glob(data_path)` should point you somewhere. It probably doesn't use the `len` function directly.

Comment: Read the code of ```glob``` and you find the source of the error